# Azure Portal shows Error page when viewing app registration overview

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

Cloud products are not supposed to have this kind of errors - right?
Until last night I was able to do app registration, this overview blade for the app registration is showing an Error page. "Error displaying your content with the following text.
My Role is: Global Administrator in this Azure AD Free tenant for my Pay as you go subscription.

> _errorData: undefined _sourceErrorLevel: undefined baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"] code: undefined data: undefined
> errorLevel: 2 extension: fx handled: undefined innerErrors: ["message:
> Cannot read property 'style' of null\r\nstack: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'style' of null\n at new t
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/kZ-OXFHhsTp2.js:4:9647)\n at
> afterMount
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:91:2697)\n
> at Object.u [as applyBindings]
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/SiztLdHCcRga.js:74:197)\n at
> t.n.render
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/SiztLdHCcRga.js:78:2223)\n
> at new t
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:88:1454)\n
> at p
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:89:789)\n at
> Object.nt [as applyToElement]
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:89:572)\n at
> ft
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:91:2494)\n
> at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:91:3678\n
> at wr
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fMde2SuDCDiV.js:6:1111)\r\n"]
> message: Failed to load the control module
> 'MsPortalImpl/Controls/Controls.Essentials'. Error: Cannot read
> property 'style' of null name: Error source: undefined stack:
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at new t
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/kZ-OXFHhsTp2.js:4:9647) at
> afterMount
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:91:2697) at
> Object.u [as applyBindings]
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/SiztLdHCcRga.js:74:197) at
> t.n.render
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/SiztLdHCcRga.js:78:2223) at
> new t
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:88:1454) at
> p (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:89:789) at
> Object.nt [as applyToElement]
> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:89:572) at
> ft (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:91:2494)
> at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/jXQsRyf4QvZT.js:91:3678 at
> wr (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fMde2SuDCDiV.js:6:1111)
> timestamp: 3697504.9749999307 type: MsPortalFx.Errors.Error

Comment: Try: 1.refresh the portal 2.change a browser 3.use a Privacy mode of the browser.

Comment: I am not sure if it was a temporary issue. I had even created a new app registration and it was giving the same error. But I just refreshed the browser and the overview page came back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a temporary issue, the Global Administrator is enough to access the App Registration.

Try to refresh the portal, change a browser, or use a privacy mode of the browser.